# Apache server wrong certificate chain

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate

I want to install multi certificate for my website(ECC and RSA).
And this is my config for apache:

```
#ECC
SSLCertificateFile ECCcertificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ECCprivate.key

#RSA
SSLCertificateFile RSAcertificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile RSAprivate.key
```

The chain and certificate is include in both certificate file like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ECC certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ECC chain 1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ECC chain 2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
RSA certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
RSA chain 1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
RSA chain 2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I test my website in ssllabs and it says "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B."
My server return ECC certificate with RSA chain.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: For what it is worth, I don't believe you can have two public keys in a  certificate. For example, you can have RSA or you can have elliptic curve; but you can't have both.